Problema redirección PHP al crear vCard (.vcf)
Colegas, tengo este código para crear una vCard, solo que después de ser ejecutado el código quiero que redireccione a otra pagina sin embargo no funciona con el window.location.replace
Intente realizarlo con el header('Location: /inicio.php'), pero me arrojaba error PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/
Otra problema que tengo es que si me crea el .vcf, pero al descargarlo en un celular e intentar importarlo como contacto, no abre el archivo, aunque si lo leo en un editor de texto, contiene todos los elementos de forma correcta
como podre resolverlo?
header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard; charset=CHARSET=utf-8;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "'.$nameVcf.'.vcf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Connection: close');

$rutaImagen = "logo.jpg";
$getPhoto = file_get_contents($rutaImagen);
$b64vcard = base64_encode($getPhoto);
$b64mline = chunk_split($b64vcard,74,"\n");
$b64final = preg_replace('/(.+)/', ' $1', $b64mline);
$photoBase64 = $b64final;

// Data vCard
$vCard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";
$vCard .= "VERSION:4.0\r\n";
$vCard .= "CLASS:PUBLIC\r";

$vCard .= "FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:".$fn." \r\n";
$vCard .= "N;CHARSET=UTF-8:".$nombre." \r\n";
$vCard .= "ORG;CHARSET=UTF-8:Empresa SA \r\n";
$vCard .= "TITLE;CHARSET=UTF-8:".$cargo." \r\n";
$vCard .= "URL:https://www.empresa.com/ \r\n";

$vCard .= "TEL;TYPE=WORK,voice:222-222-2222 \r\n";
$vCard .= "TEL;TYPE=CELL,voice:".$celular." \r\n";
$vCard .= "EMAIL;PREF;WORK:".$email." \r\n";
$vCard .= "ADR;PREF;WORK:Priv. Tecamachalco No. 2531, Colonia, CDMX, México \r\n";

// Foto o logo
$vCard .= "PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:";
$vCard .= $photoBase64 . "\r\n";

// Finalizamos vCard
$vCard .= "END:VCARD\r\n";

echo $vCard;

echo "<script>window.setTimeout(function() { window.location.replace = '/inicio.php' }, 3000);</script>";

